# Magento site: Tapping thumbnail photo doesn't change large photo on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, mobile, prototypejs

I'm working with a Magento site and I'm new to Magento so please bear with me. I originally [asked this question in the Magento community](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55110/tapping-thumbnail-photo-doesnt-change-large-photo-on-mobile), but they told me it was off-topic. I'm hoping StackOverflow can help.

When viewing certain products, clicking/tapping on a thumbnail image does not reload the large image. Instead, when I click/tap on the images, the browser jumps back to the top of the page and a hash (#) gets appended to the URL. This, of course, leads me to believe there's a JS problem somewhere, but I don't see anything in my console about it.

**Chrome Console errors:**

```
The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
cg-ball-cap-adjustable.html:114 

GET http://[my url]/skin/frontend/gpmd/default/js/vendor/lightbox.min.map 404 (Not Found)
cg-ball-cap-adjustable.html:1
```

**Safari Console errors:**

```
[Error] Viewport argument key "target-densitydpi" not recognized and ignored.
(result, line 106)

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(lightbox.min.map, line 0)
```

These errors don't look like they could be causing my problem, but I guess I'm not 100% sure on that.

**Other weirdness:**

Sometimes--inconsistently but usually after reloading the page--I get this JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
prototype.js:828
```

Chrome points me to prototype's error catch line. When I look in Firefox, Firebug gives me a little more info on this error:

```
TypeError: prevConfig.config is undefined
if(prevConfig.config.allowedProducts
configurable.js (line 184)
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="product-media" class="product-media">
    <div id="product-main" class="product-media-large">
        <a class="product-image" data-lightbox="product-image-1" title="" href="[my url]/placeholder/default/thumbnail-large.jpg">
            <img id="product-zoom" class="image" src="[my url]/placeholder/default/thumbnail-large.jpg" width="476" height="610" alt="" data-zoom-image="[my url]/placeholder/default/thumbnail-large.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="view-full-link">
            <a data-lightbox="product-image-2" href="[my url]/placeholder/default/thumbnail-large.jpg">View Full Size</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product-thumbs-gallery">
        <div id="product-thumbs" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides carousel">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="carousel-link active" data-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1.jpg" title="">
                        <img class="carousel-image" src="[my url]/thumbnail-1.jpg" width="115" height="115" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="carousel-link " data-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1_5th_copy_.jpg" data-zoom-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1_5th_copy_.jpg" title="">
                        <img class="carousel-image" src="[my url]/thumbnail-1_5th_copy_.jpg" width="115" height="115" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="carousel-link " data-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1_copy_.jpg" data-zoom-image="[my url]/thumbnail-1_copy_.jpg" title="">
                        <img class="carousel-image" src="[my url]/thumbnail-1_copy_.jpg" width="115" height="115" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Background info:**

I didn't build this site. I inherited it and am trying to find my way through things. Therefore, I'm not sure if I've provided enough information for you all to help me. I can edit this with any additional info that may be helpful.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have javascript conflict, try to add jquery.conflict() in flexslider script. You may find the script from [root]/skin/frontend/[yourpackage or default]/theme/.

Also you can try adding the flexslider script in footer. You need to check the layout files([root]/app/design/frontend/[yourpackage or default]/theme/layout/page.xml or catalog.xml etc.)  where this library has been added.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had the same problem and I solved it by removing jQuery conflict between two different versions. How to achieve this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page